# Move table rows up and down - Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

Can anyone please tell me how to move table rows up and down through jQuery/Javascript.

I have a table and for each row a radio button is there in the first td. On clicking the up/down arrows the selected rows should move up/down.

Looking forward for some ideas...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First get the selected row:

```
var radio;
// assuming there's only one form in your page, replace 0 with whatever it is
// and inputs have name 'radioGroupName'
for (var i in document.forms[0].radioGroupName) {
    if (documents.forms[0].radioGroupName[i].checked) {
        radio = documents.forms[0].radioGroupName[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        break;
    }
}
```

To shift up:

```
var prev = radio.previousSibling;
var par = radio.parentNode;
if (prev) {
    par.removeChild(radio);
    par.insertBefore(radio, prev);
}
```

To shift down:

```
var next = radio.nextSibling;
var par = radio.parentNode;
par.removeChild(radio);
if (next.nextSibling)
    par.insertBefore(radio, next.nextSibling);
else
    par.appendChild(radio);
```

Comment: Thanks, works really well. Should the third line in the "To shift down" be: par.removeChild(radio);

Comment: Yes it should. Thanks, fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example as requested by Nahom. It's an abbreviated version of what I'm using in my project. The green symbol on the right is for dragging, the red 'x' is for deleting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
      <body bgcolor=white>
        <table width=100% height=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
          <tr>
            <td valign=top style="padding: 5px;" rowspan=2 height=99%>
              <script language="JavaScript">
                function get( e ){ return( document.getElementById( e ) ); }

                function findPosX( obj )
                {
                  var curleft = 0;
                  if( obj.offsetParent )
                  {
                    while( obj.offsetParent )
                    {
                      curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
                      obj = obj.offsetParent;
                    }
                  }
                  else if( obj.x )  curleft += obj.x;
                  return( curleft );
                }

                function findPosY( obj )
                {
                  var curtop = 0;
                  if( obj.offsetParent )
                  {
                    while( obj.offsetParent )
                    {
                      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
                      obj = obj.offsetParent;
                    }
                  }
                  else if( obj.y ) curtop += obj.y;
                  return( curtop );
                }

                function getClickX( e )
                {
                  if( !e ) e = event;
                  var scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft;
                  if( scrollLeft <= 0 && document.documentElement )
                  {
                    scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                  }
                  return( e.clientX + scrollLeft );
                }

                function getClickY( e )
                {
                  if( !e ) e = event;
                  var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
                  if( scrollTop <= 0 && document.documentElement )
                  {
                    scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                  }
                  return( e.clientY + scrollTop );
                }

                window.onload = function()
                {
                  addTask( "" );
                };

                document.onclick = function()
                {
                  with( get("ControlDiv") )
                  {
                    style.visibility = "hidden";
                  }
                }

                function RowFromPos( table, x, y )
                {
                  if( x >= findPosX( table ) && x < findPosX( table ) + table.clientWidth )
                  {
                    if( y >= findPosY( table ) && y < findPosY( table ) + table.clientHeight )
                    {
                      for( i = 0 ; i < table.rows.length ; i++ )
                      {
                        if( x >= findPosX( table.rows[i] ) && x < findPosX( table.rows[i] ) + table.rows[i].clientWidth &&
                            y >= findPosY( table.rows[i] ) && y < findPosY( table.rows[i] ) + table.rows[i].clientHeight )
                        {
                          return( i );
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }

                  return( -1 );
                }

                var clickY = 0, dragRow = null;
                function onDragBegin( row )
                {
                  document.onmouseup = onDragDrop;
                  document.onmousemove = onDragDrag;

                  dragRow = row;
                  clickY = getClickY( event );
                  dragRow.style.backgroundColor = "gold";
                }

                function onDragDrag()
                {
                  var curX = getClickX( event );
                  var curY = getClickY( event );
                  var rowIndex = RowFromPos( get("TaskTable"), curX, curY );

                  if( rowIndex != -1 && rowIndex != dragRow.rowIndex )
                  {
                    if( rowIndex < dragRow.rowIndex )
                    {
                      // Move Up
                      var parent = dragRow.parentNode;
                      var prev = dragRow.previousSibling;
                      if( prev )
                      {
                        parent.removeChild( dragRow );
                        parent.insertBefore( dragRow, prev );
                      }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      // Move down
                      var next = dragRow.nextSibling;
                      var par = dragRow.parentNode;
                      par.removeChild( dragRow );
                      if( next.nextSibling )
                      {
                        par.insertBefore( dragRow, next.nextSibling );
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        par.appendChild( dragRow );
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }

                function onDragDrop()
                {
                  document.onmouseup = null;
                  document.onmousemove = null;

                  dragRow.style.backgroundColor = "";
                  fixTable();
                }

                function addTask( task)
                {
                  var table = get("TaskTable");
                  var row = table.insertRow( table.rows.length );

                  var cell = row.insertCell( row.cells.length );
                  cell.align = "right"; cell.vAlign = "bottom";
                  cell.width = "1%"; cell.noWrap = true;
                  cell.innerHTML = "<b>0.</b>";

                  cell = row.insertCell( row.cells.length );
                  cell.width = "99%";

                  var div = document.createElement("DIV");
                  div.designMode = "on";
                  div.contentEditable = true;
                  div.style.width = "99%";
                  div.style.height = "50px";
                  div.style.border = "1px solid black";
                  div.style.padding = "2px";
                  div.style.overflow = "scroll";
                  div.style.overflowX = "auto";
                  div.style.cursor = "text";
                  div.innerHTML = ( task != "" ? task : "<font color=\"gray\" face=\"Tahoma\">Enter task desciption here</font>" );
                  div.onfocus = function()
                  {
                    if( this.innerText == "Enter task desciption here" )
                    {
                      this.innerHTML = "";
                    }
                    event.cancelBubble = true;
                    showControlDiv( this );
                  }
                  div.onclick = function()
                  {
                    event.cancelBubble = true;
                  };
                  div.onblur = function()
                  {
                    if( this.innerText.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "") == "" )
                    {
                      this.innerHTML = "<font color=\"gray\" face=\"Tahoma\">Enter task desciption here</font>";
                    }
                  }
                  div.onselectstart = function()
                  {
                    event.cancelBubble = true;
                  };
                  cell.appendChild( div );

                  cell = row.insertCell( row.cells.length );
                  cell.width = 15; cell.align = "right"; cell.vAlign = "bottom";
                  cell.innerHTML = "<font color=red face=Tahoma size=2 style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='JavaScript: deleteTask( this.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex );'><b>X</b></a>";

                  var handle = document.createElement( "DIV" );
                  handle.innerHTML = "<font color=green size=6><b>*</b></font>";
                  handle.style.cursor = "n-resize";
                  handle.onmousedown = function()
                  {
                    onDragBegin( this.parentElement.parentElement );
                  };
                  cell.appendChild( handle );

                  fixTable();
                }

                function deleteTask( row )
                {
                  get("TaskTable").deleteRow( row );
                  fixTable();
                }

                function deleteAll()
                {
                  var table = get("TaskTable");
                  while( table.rows.length > 0 ) table.deleteRow( 0 );
                }

                function fixTable()
                {
                  var numTask = 0;
                  var table = get("TaskTable");
                  for( var i = 0 ; i < table.rows.length ; i++ )
                  {
                    numTask++;
                    table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = "<b>" + numTask + ".</b>";
                  }
                }

                function showControlDiv( parent )
                {
                  var div = get("ControlDiv");
                  var x = findPosX( parent );
                  var y = findPosY( parent );

                  div.style.top = ( y - 39 ) + "px";
                  div.style.left = x + "px";
                  div.style.width = ( parent.offsetWidth - 17 ) + "px";
                  div.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
              </script>

              <form method=post action="blah">

                <div unselectable=on id=ControlDiv style=" visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: -1000px; left: -1000px;; padding-top: 3px; padding-left: 15px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 15px; border-top-right-radius: 15px; width: 100%; height: 35px;">
                  <button unselectable=on style="border: 1px solid black; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true; document.execCommand( 'Bold' ); return( false );"><font size=4><b>B</b></b></font></button>
                  <button unselectable=on style="border: 1px solid black; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true; document.execCommand( 'Italic' ); return( false );"><font size=4><i>I</b></i></font></button>
                  <button unselectable=on style="border: 1px solid black; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true; document.execCommand( 'Underline' ); return( false );"><font size=4><u>U</b></u></font></button>
                  <!-- <button unselectable=on style="border: 1px solid black; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true; return( false );"><img src=images/img.bmp></button> -->
                  Font Face:
                  <select unselectable=on style="width: 200px; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true;" onchange="JavaScript: document.execCommand( 'FontName', false, this.value ); return( false );">
                    <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
                    <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
                    <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
                  </select>
                  Font Size:
                  <select unselectable=on style="width: 75px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true;" onchange="JavaScript: document.execCommand( 'FontSize', false, this.value ); return( false );">
                    <option value=1>1 (8pt)</option>
                    <option value=2>2 (10pt)</option>
                    <option value=3 selected>3 (12pt)</option>
                    <option value=4>4 (14pt)</option>
                    <option value=5>5 (18pt)</option>
                    <option value=6>6 (24pt)</option>
                    <option value=7>7 (36pt)</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <br><br><br>
                <table width=100% onselectstart="JavaScript: return( false );">
                  <tr>
                    <td width=1% nowrap><font size=5><b>Task List:</b></font></td>
                    <td width=33% align=center style="color: blue; font-family: Tahoma; cursor: pointer;" onclick="JavaScript: addTask( '', false );"><font size=5>+</font>&nbsp;Add Task</td>
                    <td width=33% align=center style="color: red; font-family: Tahoma; cursor: pointer;" onclick="JavaScript: if( confirm( 'Are you sure you want to delete all tasks from this template?' ) ) deleteAll();"><font size=2><b>X</b></font>&nbsp;Delete All</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table width=100% id=TaskTable cellspacing=0 onselectstart="JavaScript: return( false );"></table>
              </form>
              <br><br><br><br><br>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```