# Javascript - event is not defined error

Tags: javascript

I found the code below that someone posted in this forum which is what I need.  But this code only works in IE, not Mozilla Firefox.   This code can perform the row drag up/down (green symbol on the right).

Got this code from link:

[Move table rows up and down - Jquery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954373/move-table-rows-up-and-down-jquery-javascript)

In Mozilla Firefox, I keep getting "ReferenceError: event is not defined".  It seems to be Firefox is not recognize the event, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Can someone please help.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
      <body bgcolor=white>
        <table width=100% height=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
          <tr>
            <td valign=top style="padding: 5px;" rowspan=2 height=99%>
              <script language="JavaScript">
                function get( e ){ return( document.getElementById( e ) ); }

                function findPosX( obj )
                {
                  var curleft = 0;
                  if( obj.offsetParent )
                  {
                    while( obj.offsetParent )
                    {
                      curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
                      obj = obj.offsetParent;
                    }
                  }
                  else if( obj.x )  curleft += obj.x;
                  return( curleft );
                }

                function findPosY( obj )
                {
                  var curtop = 0;
                  if( obj.offsetParent )
                  {
                    while( obj.offsetParent )
                    {
                      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
                      obj = obj.offsetParent;
                    }
                  }
                  else if( obj.y ) curtop += obj.y;
                  return( curtop );
                }

                function getClickX( e )
                {
                  if( !e ) e = event;
                  var scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft;
                  if( scrollLeft <= 0 && document.documentElement )
                  {
                    scrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                  }
                  return( e.clientX + scrollLeft );
                }

                function getClickY( e )
                {
                  if( !e ) e = event;
                  var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
                  if( scrollTop <= 0 && document.documentElement )
                  {
                    scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                  }
                  return( e.clientY + scrollTop );
                }

                window.onload = function()
                {
                  addTask( "" );
                };

                document.onclick = function()
                {
                  with( get("ControlDiv") )
                  {
                    style.visibility = "hidden";
                  }
                }

                function RowFromPos( table, x, y )
                {
                  if( x >= findPosX( table ) && x < findPosX( table ) + table.clientWidth )
                  {
                    if( y >= findPosY( table ) && y < findPosY( table ) + table.clientHeight )
                    {
                      for( i = 0 ; i < table.rows.length ; i++ )
                      {
                        if( x >= findPosX( table.rows[i] ) && x < findPosX( table.rows[i] ) + table.rows[i].clientWidth &&
                            y >= findPosY( table.rows[i] ) && y < findPosY( table.rows[i] ) + table.rows[i].clientHeight )
                        {
                          return( i );
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }

                  return( -1 );
                }

                var clickY = 0, dragRow = null;
                function onDragBegin( row )
                {
                  document.onmouseup = onDragDrop;
                  document.onmousemove = onDragDrag;

                  dragRow = row;
                  clickY = getClickY( event );
                  dragRow.style.backgroundColor = "gold";
                }

                function onDragDrag()
                {
                  var curX = getClickX( event );
                  var curY = getClickY( event );
                  var rowIndex = RowFromPos( get("TaskTable"), curX, curY );

                  if( rowIndex != -1 && rowIndex != dragRow.rowIndex )
                  {
                    if( rowIndex < dragRow.rowIndex )
                    {
                      // Move Up
                      var parent = dragRow.parentNode;
                      var prev = dragRow.previousSibling;
                      if( prev )
                      {
                        parent.removeChild( dragRow );
                        parent.insertBefore( dragRow, prev );
                      }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      // Move down
                      var next = dragRow.nextSibling;
                      var par = dragRow.parentNode;
                      par.removeChild( dragRow );
                      if( next.nextSibling )
                      {
                        par.insertBefore( dragRow, next.nextSibling );
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        par.appendChild( dragRow );
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }

                function onDragDrop()
                {
                  document.onmouseup = null;
                  document.onmousemove = null;

                  dragRow.style.backgroundColor = "";
                  fixTable();
                }

                function addTask( task)
                {
                  var table = get("TaskTable");
                  var row = table.insertRow( table.rows.length );

                  var cell = row.insertCell( row.cells.length );
                  cell.align = "right"; cell.vAlign = "bottom";
                  cell.width = "1%"; cell.noWrap = true;
                  cell.innerHTML = "<b>0.</b>";

                  cell = row.insertCell( row.cells.length );
                  cell.width = "99%";

                  var div = document.createElement("DIV");
                  div.designMode = "on";
                  div.contentEditable = true;
                  div.style.width = "99%";
                  div.style.height = "50px";
                  div.style.border = "1px solid black";
                  div.style.padding = "2px";
                  div.style.overflow = "scroll";
                  div.style.overflowX = "auto";
                  div.style.cursor = "text";
                  div.innerHTML = ( task != "" ? task : "<font color=\"gray\" face=\"Tahoma\">Enter task desciption here</font>" );
                  div.onfocus = function()
                  {
                    if( this.innerText == "Enter task desciption here" )
                    {
                      this.innerHTML = "";
                    }
                    event.cancelBubble = true;
                    showControlDiv( this );
                  }
                  div.onclick = function()
                  {
                    event.cancelBubble = true;
                  };
                  div.onblur = function()
                  {
                    if( this.innerText.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "") == "" )
                    {
                      this.innerHTML = "<font color=\"gray\" face=\"Tahoma\">Enter task desciption here</font>";
                    }
                  }
                  div.onselectstart = function()
                  {
                    event.cancelBubble = true;
                  };
                  cell.appendChild( div );

                  cell = row.insertCell( row.cells.length );
                  cell.width = 15; cell.align = "right"; cell.vAlign = "bottom";
                  cell.innerHTML = "<font color=red face=Tahoma size=2 style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='JavaScript: deleteTask( this.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex );'><b>X</b></a>";

                  var handle = document.createElement( "DIV" );
                  handle.innerHTML = "<font color=green size=6><b>*</b></font>";
                  handle.style.cursor = "n-resize";
                  handle.onmousedown = function()
                  {
                    onDragBegin( this.parentElement.parentElement );
                  };
                  cell.appendChild( handle );

                  fixTable();
                }

                function deleteTask( row )
                {
                  get("TaskTable").deleteRow( row );
                  fixTable();
                }

                function deleteAll()
                {
                  var table = get("TaskTable");
                  while( table.rows.length > 0 ) table.deleteRow( 0 );
                }

                function fixTable()
                {
                  var numTask = 0;
                  var table = get("TaskTable");
                  for( var i = 0 ; i < table.rows.length ; i++ )
                  {
                    numTask++;
                    table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = "<b>" + numTask + ".</b>";
                  }
                }

                function showControlDiv( parent )
                {
                  var div = get("ControlDiv");
                  var x = findPosX( parent );
                  var y = findPosY( parent );

                  div.style.top = ( y - 39 ) + "px";
                  div.style.left = x + "px";
                  div.style.width = ( parent.offsetWidth - 17 ) + "px";
                  div.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
              </script>

              <form method=post action="blah">

                <div unselectable=on id=ControlDiv style=" visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: -1000px; left: -1000px;; padding-top: 3px; padding-left: 15px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 0px; border-top-left-radius: 15px; border-top-right-radius: 15px; width: 100%; height: 35px;">
                  <button unselectable=on style="border: 1px solid black; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true; document.execCommand( 'Bold' ); return( false );"><font size=4><b>B</b></b></font></button>
                  <button unselectable=on style="border: 1px solid black; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true; document.execCommand( 'Italic' ); return( false );"><font size=4><i>I</b></i></font></button>
                  <button unselectable=on style="border: 1px solid black; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true; document.execCommand( 'Underline' ); return( false );"><font size=4><u>U</b></u></font></button>
                  <!-- <button unselectable=on style="border: 1px solid black; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: inline; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true; return( false );"><img src=images/img.bmp></button> -->
                  Font Face:
                  <select unselectable=on style="width: 200px; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true;" onchange="JavaScript: document.execCommand( 'FontName', false, this.value ); return( false );">
                    <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
                    <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option>
                    <option value="Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
                  </select>
                  Font Size:
                  <select unselectable=on style="width: 75px;" onclick="JavaScript: event.cancelBubble=true;" onchange="JavaScript: document.execCommand( 'FontSize', false, this.value ); return( false );">
                    <option value=1>1 (8pt)</option>
                    <option value=2>2 (10pt)</option>
                    <option value=3 selected>3 (12pt)</option>
                    <option value=4>4 (14pt)</option>
                    <option value=5>5 (18pt)</option>
                    <option value=6>6 (24pt)</option>
                    <option value=7>7 (36pt)</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <br><br><br>
                <table width=100% onselectstart="JavaScript: return( false );">
                  <tr>
                    <td width=1% nowrap><font size=5><b>Task List:</b></font></td>
                    <td width=33% align=center style="color: blue; font-family: Tahoma; cursor: pointer;" onclick="JavaScript: addTask( '', false );"><font size=5>+</font>&nbsp;Add Task</td>
                    <td width=33% align=center style="color: red; font-family: Tahoma; cursor: pointer;" onclick="JavaScript: if( confirm( 'Are you sure you want to delete all tasks from this template?' ) ) deleteAll();"><font size=2><b>X</b></font>&nbsp;Delete All</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table width=100% id=TaskTable cellspacing=0 onselectstart="JavaScript: return( false );"></table>
              </form>
              <br><br><br><br><br>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The code you have posted does not contain the `Event` identifier mentioned in the error message.  Post the real code, and post only the relevant parts of it.

Comment: That is a real code, the error is lower case "event is not defined".

Comment: OK. Firefox does show the location of the error. This is where you should start debugging.

Comment: [event.cancelButton is not supported by Firefox][1] 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596364/whats-the-difference-between-cancelbubble-and-stoppropagation

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define your variable `event` anywhere, so you can't add properties to it.

Comment: Note the case-sensitivity of the languages. `event` is an implicit local variable in event-handler attributes in all DOMs I know. It is a property of `window`, which is in the scope chain, in MSHTML. The problem lies elsewhere. Probably a library is attempting to use or augment `Event`.

Comment: @PointedEars I believe you need to pass the event explicitly or inspect the `arguments`, no? I've never tried to access `event` in JS without declaring it.

Comment: This is only partially a language issue. Look at the event listener code carefully. `if (!e) e = event;` is equivalent to `if (!e) e = window.event;` because `window` is in the scope chain and the assumption is that only in the MSHTML DOM `e` is `undefined` (so a false-value). In the other DOM implementations, `e` will be a reference to an event object; it does not need to be passed explicitly. AISB, the problem lies elsewhere and the posted code does not contain it because it cannot be the actual code.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Sorry I posted "Event" as upper case. It should be "ReferenceError: event is not defined". @PointedEars, I am not too good with Javascript, can you let me know what I need to change?  The code is from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954373/move-table-rows-up-and-down-jquery-javascript

Comment: @Milacay Sorry, if you are copying scripts without knowing what you are doing, I cannot help you. This is not JS/DOM 101.