# jQuery looking for a plugin to dynamically move tables and updates ID's accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a way in jQuery to move dynamically tables.
I've coded actually a button to clone a hidden table when needed as well a button to delete a not needed table.

Now I'd like to add the function to change the order of those tables dynamically. But, I need the id's of the elements inside the table to be updated as well as the data will be used into a form (see sample).

```html
<TABLE id="Leg0" width="400px" border="0">
  <TR >
    <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" class="delCheckLeg" name="chk"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Date" class="datepicker" id="tripdate0" name="tripdate0"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Dep Time" id="deptime0" name="deptime0"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Departure" class="aptsearch" id="routingdep0" name="routingdep0"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Arrival" class="aptsearch" id="routingarr0" name="routingarr0"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Flight Time" id="fttime0" name="fttime0"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Pax" id="pax0" name="pax0"/></TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE id="Leg1" width="400px" border="0">
  <TR >
    <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" class="delCheckLeg" name="chk"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Date" class="datepicker" id="tripdate1" name="tripdate1"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Dep Time" id="deptime1" name="deptime1"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Departure" class="aptsearch" id="routingdep1" name="routingdep1"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Arrival" class="aptsearch" id="routingarr1" name="routingarr1"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Flight Time" id="fttime1" name="fttime1"/></TD>
    <TD><INPUT type="text" placeholder="Pax" id="pax1" name="pax1"/></TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

I've tried to use a system with [arrows to move the tables up and down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954373/move-table-rows-up-and-down-jquery-javascript) but it would be more nice with a dragging solution. For such thing, I've seen the pluggin ["Table Drag and Drop JQuery plugin"](http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/) but it seems to work only with rows&columns.

Does anyone have an idea on how to perform this?

Comment: you shouldn't need to use IDs at all. And please provide in question what you have tried

Comment: Have you looked at jquery templates? https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl  you would define a markup of html, in your case that hidden table, and use appendto to add each of the tables you want to clone.. you'd be able to supply your id's as incrementing values also with an array parameter..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with  [slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid). Slickgrid is open source library and has nice documentation and examples

Comment: thx! "Table Drag and Drop JQuery plugin"  is as well nice if I change my philosophy from multiple tables to multiples <tr> :)